Does Charles III have any political power in Australia, as head of state of this country?
According to,
Commonwealth realm

As of 2024, there are 15 Commonwealth realms: Antigua and Barbuda,
Australia, The Bahamas, Belize, Canada, Grenada, Jamaica, New Zealand,
Papua New Guinea, Saint Kitts and Nevis, Saint Lucia, Saint Vincent
and the Grenadines, Solomon Islands, Tuvalu, and the United Kingdom.
While the Commonwealth of Nations has 56 independent member states,
only these 15 have Charles III as head of state.

and according to,
Head of State

The head of state may hold significant constitutional power or exert
only the ceremonial authority associated with his or her title. For
example, the United Kingdom is a constitutional monarchy in which the
monarch, as head of state, performs an important but mainly symbolic
function in the British political system: opening each new session of
Parliament, dissolving it before a general election, formally
appointing the prime minister, and representing the country abroad.
The president of France, in contrast, possesses significant powers,
such as making treaties with foreign governments and directing the
armed forces

Does Charles III have any political power in Australia, as head of state of this country?

By "political power" are you including or excluding symbolic powers of the kind in your second quoted section?

@origimbo real political powers, not symbolic powers

We don't seem to have had this question before.  As someone rather unkeen to have Chales III as my head of state in Canada, knowing which actual prerogatives  come with the title is of interest (very few actually - even the Governor General position is uncoupled, AFAIK)  so I can see why it would interest Australians.

It depends on the situation ...
Australia has a strong republican movement. However, this movement did not yet manage to change the monarchist status quo. As of the last referendum, a majority did prefer having a monarch. So Australians do care. Yet Australia is generally understood (by the Australians and by other people) to be a sovereign and democratic nation.
Any attempt by King Charles to use the powers vested in the Crown-in-Parliament without the consent of the majority of that Parliament would trigger a constitutional crisis. Note that this is considerably more political influence over Australian affairs than other European monarchs get, so in that sense he has political power ...
If there was some sort of multi-sided political gridlock in Australian politics, the King might step in to dismiss an official or the like. There is no way he could push through an appointment against the will of the Australians.

Your hypothetical basically describes the 1975 constitutional crisis (except that this was triggered by the Governor-General, who is in theory acting in the name of the monarch but effectively not). That set a precedent that Parliament was sovereign and could not be overridden by the Monarch. After 1975, what potential is there for a constitutional crisis? The matter seems settled.

@Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil', what would happen if Charles did fire an Australian official, despite the precedent? I'd call that a constitutional crisis exactly because he is not supposed to.
